# MySQL data modeling: Multiple user types / Activity / Following

Tags: php, mysql, data-modeling

I have a project in which there is a site with multiple user types.  And I am having trouble wrapping my head around the best practice for this.

I want to be able to get activity from (nodes) you follow regardless of node type.  Pretend the node types are:

User:
Organization:

An organization will be an entity that can act as a user.  Write comments, send messages.  But an organization is made up of users who can edit the orgs information.  Organizations can also follow, and be followed.

- A) Should Users and Organizations be separate tables?
- B) Generally speaking how should this be stored.
- C) If they are in fact 2 tables, how does a join work when getting activity from those you follow?

Comment: Is an organization able to "act as a user", or are "users belonging to an organization able to act in the name of it" ?
You might want to take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key ;-)

Comment: If I belong to an organization, I can "log into" the organization.  Then I would be browsing as the organization and not acting as myself, but on behalf of the organization.

Comment: I'm working on something for you, but I have a question first: is the relationship between users and organizations many-to-many?  i.e., can a user belong to more than one organization?

Comment: No, for this purpose I think that may be a bad idea for a many-to-many.  A user can belong to 1 org.

Comment: It also seems like a user would have to login / register multiple accounts.  Their user account and their org account (if they are the owner)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's one possible approach.

The rough strategy here is this

- Accounts (i.e., access credentials) are separate from profiles (entity-specific data)
- Accounts identify the type of profile
- Profiles link back to their account with a foreign key.  Other related tables (comments, for example) would use `account.account_id` as their foreign key. Queries could then determine which profile table to use when selecting additional information.

Here's [a quick ERD](http://www.shackpics.com/viewer.x?file=sample_erd_co3zt3y5la0l81g4m530.png) I knocked up with the wonderful [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html) tool.

[erd http://www.shackpics.com/files/sample_erd_co3zt3y5la0l81g4m530.png](http://www.shackpics.com/files/sample_erd_co3zt3y5la0l81g4m530.png)

And here's the CREATE script generated by the tool for this model

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb`;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`account`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `account` (
  `account_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `account_type` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`organization_profile`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `organization_profile` (
  `organization_profile_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `account_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `organization_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`organization_profile_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_organization_profile_account` (`account_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_organization_profile_account`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_id` )
    REFERENCES `account` (`account_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`user_profile`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_profile` (
  `user_profile_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `account_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_profile_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_user_profile_account1` (`account_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_profile_account1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`account_id` )
    REFERENCES `account` (`account_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`xref_user_profile_has_organization_profile`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xref_user_profile_has_organization_profile` (
  `user_profile_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `organization_profile_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_profile_id`, `organization_profile_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_xref_user_profile_has_organization_profile_user_profile1` (`user_profile_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_xref_user_profile_has_organization_profile_organization_pro1` (`organization_profile_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_xref_user_profile_has_organization_profile_user_profile1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_profile_id` )
    REFERENCES `user_profile` (`user_profile_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_xref_user_profile_has_organization_profile_organization_pro1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`organization_profile_id` )
    REFERENCES `organization_profile` (`organization_profile_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

*Note: I **do not** advocate storing plain-text passwords. This is only a sample model to describe relationships, not cover the specifics of secure access-credential storage.*

The basic strategy here is that you would arbitrarily "give" each profile table an "account_type" number.  For example, organizations would be **1**, and users would be **2**.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like in your case organization is also an user. This is very similar to our database which looks like this,

1. You have a table with every users and organizations. We call them principals. The organization and user are treated the same in this table. This is where you store your data like activities. You can add a column for the type (org or user).
2. You would have another table for the relations. It just needs two columns, one column is organization and the other is users belong to this organization. Say an organization has 100 users, you would have 100 entries in this table for each user.